# Check if user have permission or not to download any file in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I want to check whether any user have permission or not to download any file. I have product id and user id so How I can check?

I have explored a lot on google and in woocommerce documentation but didn't find any solution.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12275#issuecomment-259122914 this link from woocommerce support, anyone can help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**2020 - Code update for WooCommerce 3+**

Here is the process to get downloadable order items information that you can use in any function or hooked function in your php files:

```php
// Get all current customer orders
$customer_orders = wc_get_orders( $args = array(
    'limit'       => -1,
    'customer_id' => get_current_user_id(), // The current user id
    'status'      => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses()),
) );

// The different loops to get the downloadable products bought by this user
if ( ! empty($customer_orders) ){
    // Loop through customer orders
    foreach ( $customer_orders as $order){
        // Check if current order has available downloadable items (permitted)
        if( $order->has_downloadable_item() && $order->is_paid() && $order->is_download_permitted() ){
            // Loop through order items with downloadable items
            foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
                $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // product ID

                // Get the downloadbles files (array):
                $downloads = $item->get_item_downloads();
                if( ! empty( $downloads ) ) {
                    // Loop through downloads
                    foreach( $downloads as $download_id => $download ) {
                        // Output formatted download name and link
                        echo '<p>' . $download['name'] . ' <a href="' . $download['download_url'] . '">' . __("Download link") . '</a></p>';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in any php file of your active child theme (or active theme)*. Tested and works.

Reference:

- [**`WC_Abstract_Order` class - Methods**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Abstract-Order.html)
- [**`WC_Order` class - Methods**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order.html)
- [**`WC_Order_Item_Product` class - Methods**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/classes/WC-Order-Item-Product.html)

Comment: Gives me `Call to undefined method WC_Order_Item_Product::is_download_permitted()`, seems like this function works only for WC_Order::...

Comment: @Fanky Sorry this was a very old answer… I have updated code…